# Two pagination in one page without being synchronous

Tags: pagination

How can I have two pagination without them being synchronous?

so let's say I have `<div class="block-a">` and `<div class="block-b">`, when I try to proceed to **Block A's** pagination result `2` which I get redirected to `page/2` and then it displays the **Block A's** page 2 results, but when I scroll down to check **Block B** it is also showing the page `2` results.

is it possible to have two pagination in one page without them being synchronous? when I go to **Block A's** page 2, **Block B** shouldn't display page `2` results.

I'm a man of SEO and tracking traffic on my site, that's why I wouldn't go for AJAX solution.